# Filing as Dual Status or Non-Resident if entered and exited the US in the same year

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, form-1040x

I'm a New Zealand citizen who emigrated (I have a green card) to the US in July. Due to some medical issues I returned to NZ in early December. My question is whether I should file as a Dual-Status or Non-resident? I'm assuming Non-Resident since I wasn't resident on the last day of the year?

Is it a good idea to file for the extension to meet the physical presence test? Or can I claim the period ending in 2014 for the physical presence test?

My long term intention is to return to the US.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a green-card, you're a US permanent resident and pass [the green-card test](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Alien-Residency---Green-Card-Test). You cannot file non-resident. You can either file as a dual-status or full-year resident.

> If you meet the green card test at anytime during the calendar year,
>   but do not meet the substantial presence test for that year, your
>   residency starting date is the first day on which you are present in
>   the United States as a Lawful Permanent Resident. However, an alien
>   who has been present in the United States at any time during a
>   calendar year as a Lawful Permanent Resident may choose to be treated
>   as a resident alien for the entire calendar year.

Comment: "However, an alien who has been present in the United States at any time during a calendar year as a Lawful Permanent Resident may choose to be treated as a resident alien for the entire calendar year." There is no basis for this for an unmarried person in either Publication 519 or the law.

Comment: You do realize that I quoted from the link, right? That's what the colored background usually means.

Answer (score 0):

You are not a nonresident alien because you pass the [Green Card Test](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222120).

But since you came to the U.S. in the middle of the year (assuming you didn't count as resident in 2013), you fall under [First Year of Residency](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222164) special rules. You are only a resident starting on the first day you entered the U.S. as a permanent resident; you are nonresident before that. Therefore you are a dual-status alien for 2014.

If you are married, you can choose to use the [Choosing Resident Alien Status](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222177) or the [Nonresident Spouse Treated as Resident](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p519/ch01.html#en_US_2014_publink1000222193) election to become a resident alien for all of 2014 and file jointly with your spouse. If you are not married, there is no way for you to be considered a resident alien for all of 2014.